# how to get parent key from multidimensional array by key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to get one of the 'main' array ('111', '222') where the 'expire' attribute is past from current timestamp.

my array is structured like this:

```php
$stored = array(
  '111' => array(
    0 => array(
      'type' => 'first',
      'expire' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2019-01-01 08:00:00')),
    ),
    1 => array(
      'type' => 'second',
      'expire' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2019-01-01 09:00:00')),
    ),
  ),
  '222' => array(
    0 => array(
      'type' => 'first',
      'expire' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2019-01-02 12:00:00')),
    ),
    1 => array(
      'type' => 'second',
      'expire' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2019-01-02 13:00:00')),
    ),
    2 => array(
      'type' => 'third',
      'expire' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2019-01-02 14:00:00')),
    ),
  ),
);
```

I did a bit of research and found `array_column` which I feel to be a part of the solution but I don't know how to apply it to my case since I tried

```php
$list = array_column($stored, 'expire');
print_r($list);
```

and it gives an empty array, so it means `array_column` doesn't work on multidimensional array..

Comment: You can use `array_filter()` with a callback that removes any values where the `expire` value is in the past.

Comment: Do you just want the first such key, or all of them? Which one of the sub-elements has such an expires value does not matter? // Before you go for the “fancy” array functions, I would recommend you try to solve this using simple foreach loops. The basic logic is usually quite trivial to formulate, whereas with the array functions you need to have a really good understanding of what they actually do …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of nested `foreach` loops are the most efficient (IMHO) as the inner loop checks for an expired entry.  As soon as one is found it flags the whole key and then moves onto the next one.  This saves having to process all of the entries and then check if any are left...

```
$expired = [];
foreach ( $stored as $key => $main )    {
    foreach ( $main as $sub )   {
        if ( strtotime($sub['expire']) < time() )   {
            $expired[] = $key;
            break;
        }
    }
}
print_r($expired);
```

If you just want the first expired one, then change

```
break;
```

to

```
break 2;
```

and it will stop both loops as soon as it finds an expired item.

Comment: Better to store `time()` in a variable?

Comment: @vivek_23 it would be better to store the items in the array as a timestamp.  it's a minor change compared to filtering through all of the items.

Comment: Agreed, but not sure why OP wants to keep it this way in date format.

Comment: at first, I wanted to avoid using loops because I thought it would bring more "burden" than "profit" (efficiency-wise). but now I think the difference would be pretty miniscule, so I will use this method. thanks everyone.

@atymic's answer is also similar to this one, but this one is easier to read for me so I'm choosing this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop over each of the collections of items, and then use `array_filter` to determine if any of the items are expired. For example:

```php
$expiredKeys = [];

foreach ($stored as $key => $items) {
    $hasExpired = count(array_filter($items, function ($item) {
        return strtotime($item['expire']) < time();
    })) > 0;

    if ($hasExpired) {
        $expiredKeys[] = $key;
    }
}

var_dump($expiredKeys);
```

Outputs:

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  int(111)
  [1] =>
  int(222)
}
```

Comment: Better to store `time()` in a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Using your code

```
// an array to hold all the expired dates
$expired = [];

$stored = array(
        '111' => array(
            0 => array(
                'type' => 'first',
                'expire' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2019-08-01 08:00:00')),
            ),
            1 => array(
                'type' => 'second',
                'expire' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2019-01-01 09:00:00')),
            ),
        ),
        '222' => array(
            0 => array(
                'type' => 'first',
                'expire' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2019-01-02 12:00:00')),
            ),
            1 => array(
                'type' => 'second',
                'expire' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2019-01-02 13:00:00')),
            ),
            2 => array(
                'type' => 'third',
                'expire' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2019-01-02 14:00:00')),
            ),
        ),
);

// Loop through the first/parent array
foreach($stored as $key => $val){
    // Get the expire index only and store into variable for use in the inner loop
    $expire_dates = array_column($val, 'expire');
    // Loop through the inner arrays
    foreach($val as $value){
        // Convert the expire date from 'Y-m-d H:i:s' to unix timestamp, it is easier and better for date comparison
        $expire = strtotime($value['expire']);
        if($expire < time() ){
            $expired[$key][] = $value['expire'];
        }
    }

}

// Now print all the expired array data
echo '<pre>';
print_r($expired);
```

Expected Output:

```
Array
(
    [111] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2019-01-01 09:00:00
        )

    [222] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2019-01-02 12:00:00
            [1] => 2019-01-02 13:00:00
            [2] => 2019-01-02 14:00:00
        )

)
```